# Django Rest API issue with retrieving correct information from urls. It is a Grandparent - Parent - Child relationship. How do I correctly map them?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have been stuck on this problem for about 9 hours and am having trouble understanding the Grandparent - Parent - Child relationship with a One to Many Relationship(foreign key) in Django.

I am currently creating an E-Commerce website and am trying to display the information in 4 different ways to fetch from my React frontend.

I have 3 models setup:
Category
Subcategory (Foreign key to Category)
Products (Foreign Key to Subcategory)

This is the result I am attempting to create in my urls/views/serializer files:
For some reason I can successfully retrieve at a granular level for a single product but as soon as I start going up nested models I am running into the following errors:

**Desired Result**

```
I have api/ included in the core urls folder already.

I want JSON to display the information like this.
# URLSearch api/Category/
# Category -
#           |
#           Subcategory 1 -
#                          |
#                           Product 1
#                           Product 2
#           Subcategory 2 -
#                          |
#                           Product 1
#                           Proudct 2

I also want JSON to display the information like this.
# URLSearch api/Category/Subcategory/
# Category -
#           |
#           Subcategory -
#                        |
#                        Product 1
#                        Product 2
```

**Errors**

Error 1:
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `slug` on serializer `SubcategoryListSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'slug'.

Error 2:
Returns Wrong Object piggies back off issue above - I deleted my code to clean it up file as I have been attempting this for 10+ hours so there is currently a place holder route there.

**Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('search/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:subcategory_slug>/',
         views.SubcategoryListView.as_view()), #Error 1
    path('search/<slug:category_slug>/', views.AllProductsListView.as_view()), # Error 2
    path('all-products/', views.AllProductsListView.as_view()),  # Good
    path('search/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:subcategory_slug>/<slug:product_slug>',
         views.ProductDetail.as_view()),  # WORKS
    # path('all-products/', views.AllProductsListView.as_view())
]
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(
        primary_key=True, max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('slug',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.slug}/'


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(
        primary_key=True, max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('category',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.category.slug}/{self.slug}/'


class Products(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    newAdd = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        primary_key=True, max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    imageOne = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    imageTwo = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    imageThree = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    colors = models.CharField(max_length=300)  # This is going to be a list
    price = models.FloatField()
    dateCreated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-dateCreated',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.subcategory.category.slug}/{self.subcategory.slug}/{self.slug}'
```

**Views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializers import AllProductsSerializer, CategorySerializer, SubcategoryListSerializer, ProductsSerializer, SubcategorySerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets, generics, views, response
from products.models import Products, Subcategory, Category

# Create your views here.


class ProductDetail(views.APIView):
    def get_object(self, category_slug, subcategory_slug, product_slug):
        obj = Products.objects.filter(subcategory__category__slug=category_slug).filter(
            subcategory=subcategory_slug).get(slug=product_slug)
        return obj

    def get(self, request, category_slug, subcategory_slug, product_slug):
        print(request)
        product = self.get_object(
            category_slug, subcategory_slug, product_slug)
        serializer = ProductsSerializer(product)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)


class SubcategoryListView(views.APIView):
    def get_object(self, category_slug, subcategory_slug):
        obj = Products.objects.filter(
            subcategory__category__slug=category_slug)
        return obj

    def get(self, request, category_slug, subcategory_slug):
        products = self.get_object(category_slug, subcategory_slug)
        serializer = SubcategoryListSerializer(products)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)


class AllProductsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AllProductsSerializer
    queryset = Products.objects.all()


class CategoryListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Category
```

**Serializers**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from products.models import Products, Category, Subcategory


class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = (
            'newAdd',
            'name',
            'slug',
            'imageOne',
            'price',
            'dateCreated',
            'get_absolute_url',
        )


class SubcategoryListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('__all__')


class SubcategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = SubcategoryListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Subcategory
        fields = (
            'slug',
            'items'
            'get_absolute_url',
        )


class AllProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('__all__')


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Comment: see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: @AshwinBande thank you! I have been through the documentation multiple times and attempted Nested relationships, Generic Relationships, HyperlinkedIdentity field and many mores. Do you know what topics I should be looking up to find the correct documentation open to anything to resolve this.

Comment: remove dunder method (__str__) from your models. that is used when you want to appear model name as field on django admin panel.

Comment: @pradetto5 that is the link to the exact section you need. try adding `subcategory_set = SubcategorySerializer(many=True)` in `CategorySerializer` which will return a nested result.